# Get all versions of the file in all history, changesets

Tags: tfs, tfvc

Is there a `tf command` that will extract all versions of `config.json` file, from all changesets?

I want to see how it was changed in the course of development.

I use Team Foundation Server 2012 (v11).

Comment: Is there a reason you're still using TFS 11? It's out of support now. Are you not able to view history on the file in Visual Studio?

Comment: @spikey_richie Customer uses it. Yes, I can view the history of each individual file and see the changes, that works very well. I need to analyze the changes across multiple files in history and identify changes, so I need all available history exported, for this config file. Too many changesets to manually extract files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to script that... Using PowerShell or something similar.

Use:

```
tf history /collection:{{https://server/collection}} {{$/project/path/file}} /format:brief /noprompt
```

to grab all unique changesets for the file. Extract the numbers for each line in the table. A regex is an easy way... `^\d+` on each line should grab the number from the start of each line.

Then create a local workspace to get the copies of the file, the basic structure should look like this, but you'll need to script the loop and variable insertions:

```
md temp
cd temp
tf workspace /new /noprompt temporary-workspace /collection:{{https://server/collection}}
tv workfold /map $/project/path . /collection:{{https://server/collection}}

## foreach {{changesetnumber}} in {{history}}
tf get /version:c{{changesetnumber}} /overwrite /force /noprompt {{$/project/path/}}config.json 

copy config.json ..\config.json.{{changesetnumber}}
## end forach

tf workspace /delete temporary-workspace
```

That should create a numbered copy of the file for each changeset.

The powershell script below works for me, but is still a bit rough:

```
$tf = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe"
$collectionUri = "https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing"
$path = '$/agile2017'
$file = "xxxxxxx"

$history = & $tf history /collection:$collectionUri $path/$file /format:brief /noprompt
$changesets = $history | %{ Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern "^\d+" }
$changesets = $changesets.Matches | %{ $_.value }

cd $env:temp
md temporary-workspace -force
md history -Force
cd temporary-workspace
& $tf workspace /new /noprompt temporary-workspace /collection:$collectionUri
& $tf workfold /map $path . 

foreach ($changeset in $changesets)
{
    & $tf get /version:c$changeset /overwrite /force /noprompt $path/$file 
    copy "$file" "..\history\$file.$changeset" -Force
}

& $tf workspace /delete temporary-workspace
cd ..
rd temporary-workspace -Recurse
```

Comment: I assume `tf vc` is for newer versions, because I get 'Unrecognized command: vc.'. Without 'vc' works OK, just `tf history...`.

Comment: Yeah visual studio 2017 added the 'vc' and 'git' qualifiers. If you're on an older version, ignore the 'vc' addition.

Comment: You can use a newer version of VS to connect to TFS without issues as well, sometimes you get a few performance gains and some extra commands that previously required the TFS Power Tools.

Comment: Glad it works! Feel free to edit/update the answer in care you had to make any adjustments.

Comment: It works, but I was also hoping it would be more obvious which files in the history have been merged from common ancestor, and which one was the common ancestor. So I just posted more precise question.